# Weight covers too large an area, more elements moving

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

I've tried everything, at the start I had a problem with getting the armature to work with the mesh - I fixed it after hours and now it's happening, when I move one bone, three pieces move...

Changing envelope (3 picture) isn't working
I've tried to paint it over by hand, but it's going to take me hours and it's still doesn't look good
Still everything moves.

Same thing happens when I try move head (eyes drowning in the head)

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The weight paint pics-- if autoweight based-- suggest backwards normals.  Check, fix, re-autoweight if that's the case.  Bone envelopes are bad.  Don't use them.